# Showing step-by-step answers for power series identities?

Tags: series-expansion

We have

```
Sum[1/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}] (* Evaluate to Pi^2/6 *)
```

..but is there a way to show how this is derived step-by-step?

NOTE: I have seen step-by-step analysis for derivatives and integrals in other questions on this site, but not for power series.

Comment: *Mathematica* seems to compute that series by table lookup; see [Hansen, 1975, (5.12.46)](https://books.google.com/books?id=RRPvAAAAMAAJ&dq=Hansen+Table+of+Series+and+Product+%22%285.12.46%29%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=5.12.46); try ``TracePrint[
 Sum[1/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}],
 _Sum`SumHansen1,
 TraceInternal -> True,
 TraceAction -> (Print[ReleaseHold[#]] &)
 ]``